# Add response header based on another header in Lighttpd

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, lighttpd, response-headers, http-content-length

I have a situation where I want to use "Content-Length" header from another domain with Lighttpd using XHR HEAD request but I get `Refused to get unsafe header 'content-length'` message.

My idea is to add response header based on another response header in lighttpd.conf:

`setenv.add-response-header = ('X-Content-Length' => GET_MY_RESPONSE_HEADER('Content-Length'))`

Is there a way to write `GET_MY_RESPONSE_HEADER()` function/property in config file?

Comment: You could do so in Lua using [mod_magnet](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModMagnet).

Comment: I tried `mod_magnet` and failed. Lighty doesn't have access to COntent-Length header.

Comment: Really ? I would expect it to be in `lighty.header[]`...

Comment: You see, setting Content-length wrongly may result in the connection pipeline breaking, a timeout or even garbled text taken as a request. It is something that only the content-generating module or script can reasonably set. I suggest that you redirect this HEAD request to a custom php script and have it handled there. You may not have any other option anyway.